# Where to store custom app parameters in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I need to store "hostName" parameter in my Spring MVC application configuration (for writing links in templates to static recourses, which are on static.hostName). I assume hardcoding this is bad, so where should I store it?

Web.xml, or servlet-context.xml? And how do I get it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a [`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x//javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) you can externalize beans (and primitives) into a properties file. You can inject those beans with SpEl and [`@Value`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html):

```
@Value("${hostname}")
private String hostname;
```

You can find a [configuration example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) in the reference documentation.

Comment: I got where mistake was. I created the class with `hostname` field by myself with `new CClassName()`, when I was supposed to rely on Spring to get things done. So I annotated class with `@Component` and annotated private field with type of that class with `@Autowired`.